# Update value in TabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a main method that looks like this:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int total=0;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Placing Orders");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
        tp.addTab ("Bienvenido", new Instrucciones());
        Pizza pi;
        tp.addTab ("Tamaño de pizza", pi = new Pizza());
        Beverages be;
        tp.addTab ("Selección de bebidas", be = new Beverages());
        SpecialItems spe;
        tp.addTab ("Toppings", spe = new SpecialItems());
        CostoFinal costo = new CostoFinal(pi,be,spe);
        tp.addTab("Precio Final", costo);

        frame.getContentPane().add(tp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Each of the classes, `Pizza`, `Beverages`, `CostoFinal` and  `SpecialItems` extend JPanel, the class `CostoFinal` displays a Label depending on the state of pi,be and spe. However, it only shows the result for their initial state. How do I keep up with the changes of the instance variables of each JPanel?

Comment: Each of those classes is responsible for updating its own components.  For example, if `Pizza` has a `size` variable, when your code changes that variable, you must also write code that updates the JLabel or JTextField or JSpinner which displays that value.